# what the difference of keys and values in dictionary of swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying the tutor of swift, and found the question.

I need to use optional values to keys and then unwrap it, however the values don't to be done so.But why?

Don't know why to use "kinds" rather than kind in the closure, but the one before that used number rather than numbers  ,and how can I use numbers to get same result?

```
let interestingnumbers = [
    "prime": [2,3,5,7,9,11,21],
    "fibonacci": [1,23,5,32,4,123,11],
    "dadgadfgh":[1,2,4,5,43,6,576,12],
    "square": [1243325,123,455,1111],
]

var thekind:String?
var max=0
for (kinds,numbers) in interestingnumbers{
    for kind in kinds{
        for number in numbers{
            if number>max {
                max=number
                thekind = kinds   // I don't know why here should use "kinds" rather than kind, but the one before that used number rather than numbers  ,and how can I use numbers to get same result?
            }
        }
    }
}
print(max,thekind!)
```

---

```
//this is a fault code
let interestingnumbers = [
    "prime": [2,3,5,7,9,11,21],
    "fibonacci": [1,23,5,32,4,123,11],
    "dadgadfgh":[1,2,4,5,43,6,576,12],
    "square": [1243325,123,455,1111],
]
var thekind:String
var max=0
for (kinds,numbers) in interestingnumbers{
    for kind in kinds{
        for number in numbers{
            if number>max {
                max=number
                thekind = kinds
            }
        }
    }
}
print(max,thekind)
```

---

```
//and i tried this also
let interestingnumbers = [
    "prime": [2,3,5,7,9,11,21],
    "fibonacci": [1,23,5,32,4,123,11],
    "dadgadfgh":[1,2,4,5,43,6,576,12],
    "square": [1243325,123,455,1111],
]
var thekind:String?
var max:Int?  //also [:Int]? 
for (kinds,numbers) in interestingnumbers{
    for kind in kinds{
        for number in numbers{
            if number>max {
                max=numbers
                thekind = kinds
            }
        }
    }
}
print(max,thekind!)
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) "I need to use optional values to keys and then unwrap it, however the values don't to be done so.But why?"

This is not true. You can initialize `thekind` string variable with an empty string the same way you did with your integer type `max` setting its initial value to zero.

---

b) "Don't know why to use "kinds" rather than kind in the closure, but the one before that used number rather than numbers ,and how can I use numbers to get same result?"

You are unnecessarily iterating each character of your dictionary keys. Thats why you are assigning `kinds` `String` instead of `kind` `Character`.

---

```
let interestingnumbers = [
    "prime": [2,3,5,7,9,11,21],
    "fibonacci": [1,23,5,32,4,123,11],
    "dadgadfgh":[1,2,4,5,43,6,576,12],
    "square": [1243325,123,455,1111],
]
var thekind: String = ""
var max = 0
for (key, numbers) in interestingnumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > max {
            max = number
            thekind = key 
        }
    }
}
print(max, thekind)  // "1243325 square\n"
```

---

Just for fun the functional approach:

```
// result is a tuple (kind and max)
// reduce iterates every key value pair
// $0 is the accumulated which in this case it is used to hold the max value and the corresponding key
// $1 is the current key,value pair (kind, numbers)
let (kind, max) = interestingnumbers.reduce(into: ("",0)) {
    // here we check if the current value has a maximum value and if it is greater than $0.1 (the resulting tuple maxValue)
    if let maxValue = $1.value.max(), maxValue > $0.1 {
        // if true assign a new tuple to the result with the new key and the new maximum value
        $0 = ($1.key, maxValue)
    }
}
print(kind, max)  // "square 1243325\n"
```

Comment: So, what's the difference between  $1.value.max() and $1.value; I tried the later one and got an error. And why the $0.1 represents the resulting tuple maxvalue... which means $0.0 as the key of resulting tuple ?

Comment: @ryw $1.value refers to all values `[Int]`, `.max()` return the maximum value from the collection. `$0` refers to the result which is a tuple, the first element of the tuple is a string (key/kind) `.0` the second is an integer (max value) `.1`

Comment: Got it. So the .max() is a function rather not refer to the value "max" and once use it, we can easily get the maximum value in one key which means we just need to compare the maximum number in each key.

Comment: Yes max/min are two methods on collection that returns the maximum/minimum values. they also have an option to pass a predicate which is not needed in this case.

Comment: I changed $1.key to $1.0, but the playground showed different loop iterations, former are 2 times and latter are 3...why is that?

Comment: Don't worry about that. It doesn't mean anything.  `$1.key` and `$1.0` are the same thing. key is preferred for readability.

Comment: note that most of the time when coding in Swift `$0.0` and `$0.1` can be also written as `$0` and `$1`. Of course here it is not possible.

Comment: I found an example, did you mean the condition that in one array like```let coffee: [String] = ["Cappuccino", "Espresso", "Latte", "Ristretto"]   reverseOrder = coffee.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 } )```

Answer (score 0):

Swift's standard library doesn't have this `flatMap` overload, which makes things easy.

```swift
// (key: "square", value: 1243325)
interestingNumbers.flatMap().max(by: \.value)
```

```swift
public extension Dictionary where Value: Sequence {
  /// Flatten value sequences,
  /// pairing each value element with its original key.
  func flatMap() -> [(key: Key, value: Value.Element)] {
    flatMap { key, value in value.map { (key, $0) } }
  }
}
```

```
public extension Sequence {
  func max<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by getComparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> Element? {
    try self.max {
      try getComparable($0) < getComparable($1)
    }
  }
}
```